# Django: update field of ManyToMany instance when it's set

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-3.0

Is it possible to do something when setting ManyToMany relations with `.set()`?

Let's say, we have:

```
class ModelA():
  b_models = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB, related_name="as", through="ModelMN")

class ModelMN():
  model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
  model_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
```

And when we have an instance of **Model A** and list of **Model B** instances:

```
a = ModelA()
a.set([b1, b2, b3])
```

When calling `.set()`, an instace of **ModelMN** is created for every a-b relationship. Is it possible to modify a field of that instance (every ModelMN instance), everytime it is created?

Overriding `.save()` method on `ModelMN` seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for `m2m_changed` signal.

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=ModelA.b_models.through)
function do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
```